# How to get Yesterdays's date in a query?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

`current_date` gets only today, how can i get yesterday in Hive query ?

using `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24, ‘yyyy-MM-dd’)` is not so trivial and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

select `date_add(current_date,-1)` 
solved my issue.
+1 would be tomorrow.